# Python Console Prompt shows In[] Out[] Instead of >>> in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm assisting a Intro to Python course and one of the students has a command prompt that looks like:

```
In[0]: 1 + 2
Out[0]: 3
```

Instead of the usual:

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
```

How do we get her back to the usual ">>>" prompt?  She is running Python 3.6 on Windows using PyCharm.

Comment: you at some point configured pycharm to use ipython

Comment: note: there are lots of compelling reasons to use ipython, such as better tab completion and access to docstrings

Comment: *"How do we get her back to the usual ">>>" prompt?"*  If you learn about [IPython](https://ipython.org/), you might find yourself asking the question "How do I set up *all* my students' computers to use IPython?" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is IPython Mode.  You can disable it in settings:

[image]